# how do i string_agg these accounts together?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

i've got a table that's kinda like this

| id | account |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 333-333-2 |
| 111111 | 333-333-1 |
| 222222 | 444-444-1 |
| 222222 | 555-555-1 |
| 222222 | 555-555-2 |

and i'm trying to aggregate everything up to look like this

| id | account |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 333-333-1, -2 |
| 222222 | 444-444-1, 555-555-1, -2 |

so far i've got this

```
SELECT 
id, 
CONCAT((STRING_AGG(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(account FROM '^(([^-]*-){2})'), ', ')), 
       (STRING_AGG(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(account FROM '[^-]*$'), ', '))) account
GROUP BY id
```

but this produces

| id | account |
| --- | --- |
| 111111 | 333-333-1, 2 |
| 222222 | 444-444-, 555-555-1, 2 |

Comment: Attempting to do such operation goes against any dbms logic and violating Normal Forms. Plus, it's very expensive to obtain such output. That's most likely the reason of the downvote to this post. Why are you trying to get such output?

Comment: I see, this is just part of the table I was provided and I was told to reformat it that way. I don't see a way I could do it but are there any suggestions you have for me to somehow get that output by maybe changing up the way the table and/or schema is set up?

Comment: @lemon Normal forms are for storage, not for query processing. I don't see anything wrong with this.

Comment: If they happen to store the output of this query, dealing in future with this kind of data becomes very messy. I wouldn't even attempt to carry out this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

```
, A AS (
SELECT id,
                SUBSTRING(account FROM '^(([^-]*-){2})') first_account,
                STRING_AGG(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(account FROM '[^-]*$'), ', ') second_account
FROM table         
GROUP BY id, first_account
)
select id, STRING_AGG(DISTINCT first_account || second_account, ', ')
FROM A
GROUP BY id
```

i ended up figuring it out and this worked for me :))

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different approach: first split the account numbers into main part and suffix, then do separate grouping operations on them:

```
SELECT
  id,
  string_agg(accounts, ', ') AS account
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    concat(account_main, string_agg(account_suffix, ', ')) AS accounts
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      substr(account, 1, 7) AS account_main,
      substr(account, 8, 9) AS account_suffix
    FROM
      example
  ) AS t1
  GROUP BY
    id,
    account_main
) AS t2
GROUP BY
  id;
```